# How To Calculate Date From Day Number In Excel

Tags: date, excel-2010

I have a small application built in Excel.  It is a time management workbook where I record the hours worked on projects for each month.

In one column I have the possible days 
e.g. 
DAY 1
DAY 2
DAY 3
DAY 4
....
DAY 22

for the possible 22 workdays in a month. I have a worksheet for each month.

For each of those day numbers how would I calculate the date for that day in the Month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `WORKDAY` - Does the following helps?

[image]